# Docx4j identify Table end Tag

Tags: java, tags, docx4j

Is there a way from Java using docx4j to identify that the table ended (identify table end tag)?

I'm looking everywhere and I can't seem to find a way for the code to identify any end tag let alone the table end tag.

Comment: What are you trying to do? For example: Insert something after the end tag

Comment: Yes I'm constructing a file and I want to insert a new line after the table has finished.

Comment: So you need to find the table, then its index in the content list which contains it, then add your new line object (an org.docx4j.wml.P?).

Comment: Not really, I need to insert a new line after the closing tag of the table. So I need to somehow parse the closing tag of the table

Comment: No, you don't.  You need to add the "new line object" after the table object

Comment: So how could I do that ?

Comment: To find the table use either XPath or https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/finders/TableFinder.java

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In docx4j, a table is represented by a org.docx4j.wml.Tbl object.

There is no representation of its end tag at the object level.

But you can add something before the end tag, as it were, by adding it to the Tbl object.

Or you can add something after it, by adding to the content list containing the Tbl object.

If you need want to work at the level of the actual XML, you can marshall the content to a String, DOM or whatever, manipulate it, then unmarshall.  But in practise this isn't usually necessary.  (Though marshalling to a string is often handy for debugging)